# Upgrading GWT from 1.7 to 2.0

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2, gxt

I am trying to upgrade GWT 1.7.0 to 2.0.0 but I get the following error.

`Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/src/lib/gxt.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/Component.java'`

As per the below link I did everything as shown.

[How to upgrade GWT from 1.7 to 2.0](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.0/ReleaseNotes_2_0#Upgrading)

I am guessing there is no need to upgrade GXT. The GXT version I'm using is 1.2.5
Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a compatibility problem with GXT and GWT. According to the GXT website you need to upgrade your gxt version to at least version 2.0.2. Try downloading GXT 2.2.5 (non-commercial version) and try it out with GWT 2.0 or even 2.4.

Reference to this is [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?82099-GXT-and-GWT-2.0-Cannot-reduce-the-visibility-of-the-inherited-method-from-Widget)

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will try gxt 2.0.2 and see. I already tried GXT 2.2.5 with both GWT 2.0 and 2.4 but my project uses some of the deprecated classes in GXT 1.2.5 which are no longer available in GXT 2.2.5 and so I get compiler errors.

Comment: Unfortunately GXT 2.0.2 also does not contain some classes that are in 1.2.5

Comment: Those classes are

`com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.toolbar.AdapterToolItem

com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.toolbar.TextToolItem
com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window.CloseAction
`

Comment: 'AdapterToolItem' and 'TextToolItem' exist in gxt 1.2.5 but have been removed in 2.2.5. It seems the entire com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window package has been removed. Best thing to do is to find a replacement for those classes. You can use 1.2.5 and find a way with regular GWT classes to perform the same action as 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window.CloseAction'

Comment: Can you check once in this link it may help to you. http://www.javatbrains.com/2015/05/error-while-installing-gwt-plugin-in.html